# PhoneGap build error "plugin unsupported: ..."

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, coldfusionbuilder

**The following config.xml results in error:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<widget  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"  xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"  id="LogIn"  version="1.0.1"  versionCode="10" > 
<name>...</name>
<description>...</description>
<author >...</author>
<preference  name="phonegap-version"  value= "3.5.0"  />
<preference  name="orientation"  value= "default"  />
<preference  name="target-device"  value= "universal"  />
<preference  name="fullscreen"  value= "true"  />
<preference  name="webviewbounce"  value= "true"  />
<preference  name="android-installLocation"  value= "internalOnly"  />
<preference  name="splash-screen-duration"  value= "0"  />
<preference  name="load-url-timeout"  value= "20000"  />
<access  origin="*"  />

<feature  name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"  />
<feature  name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"  />
<feature  name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"  />
<feature  name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"  />
<feature  name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"  />
<feature  name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts"  />
<feature  name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"  />
<feature  name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"  />

<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.device" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.camera" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.file" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.media" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" ></gap:plugin>
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.4.3" ></gap:plugin>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" source="npm" />

</widget>
```

**Error message:**

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reBkM.png)

The codebase is inherited and as I understand, the configuration used to compile correctly. Removing the plugin in the error results in the following plugin on the list taking its place in the error.

Changing

```
<preference  name="phonegap-version"  value= "3.5.0"  />
```

to

```
<preference  name="phonegap-version"  value= "3.7.0"  />
```

and formatting the plugins from

```
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" ></gap:plugin>
```

to

```
<gap:plugin  name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" source="npm" ></gap:plugin>
```

seems to allow it to build, but the plugins do not function in the App.

Any and all help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PhoneGap PGB Shut Down:
http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/10/13/pgb-repository-shutting-down/

Comment: Start Using NPM for PhoneGap:
http://netkow.com/post/153144223795/using-npm-for-phonegapbuild-plugins-now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**For any of you having the same problem, I found a solution:**

**What it boils down to:**

Go to:
[PhoneGap Plugins Page](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins)

(I'm using contacts as an example here) and click on the [Old Plugins] tab. Now find your plugin and open its link under the [PBG Plugin ID] column. Use the

`<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" spec="0.2.16" source="pgb" />`

as described under [Usage Instructions] and replace `source="pgb"` with `source="npm"`.

If this fails, make use of "Option 3" on the comments above "Start Using NPM for PhoneGap" artice where you use the [Repository] link under [Other Details] on your PhoneGap Plugin page in your plugin like so:

```
<plugin spec=“https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts.git” source=“git” />
```

I hope this saves a few people a couple of hours!