# PhoneGap Android Build Error: Old Versions and Plugins

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, coldfusionbuilder

I found a solution to the following issue and I would just like to document the solution for any people who have the same problem.

In the PhoneGap Android build log I have the following error:

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-file-opener2" at "2.0.7" for android
 Using this version of Cordova with older version of cordova-android is being deprecated. Consider upgrading to cordova-android@5.0.0 or newer.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILE OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Buildfile: /project/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 25.2.5

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: appname
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 24.0.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for appname...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.0.1
[gettarget] API level:        21
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for appname...

BUILD FAILED
/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:573: ../../../../../../android-sdk/com.android.support:support-v4:+ resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project /project
```

My project's `config.xml`:

```
...
<preference  name="phonegap-version"  value="3.7.0"  />
...
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" source="npm" />
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now in the error you will note that the installation attempts

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-file-opener2" at "2.0.7" for android
```

as the same plugin in `config.xml` has no set version it will automatically attempt to use the latest version.

Following the steps in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995204/phonegap-build-error-plugin-unsupported) you will find the [latest version](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1117) of this plugin to work with `PhoneGap version 3.7.0` is  `File Opener Plugin 1.0.11` and not the install's attempted `2.0.7` so adding `spec="1.0.11"` to the plugin to look like:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" spec="1.0.11" source="npm" />
```

will force it to use the compatible version. I assume this will translate to any old plugin not being built.