# Phonegap build error cordova plugin unsupported

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need to rebuild a fairly old phoneGap app (2015). The config.xml now generates the following error:

plugin unsupported: org.apache.cordova.camera

This app uses plugins from the PhoneGap Build repository. These plugins won't be accessible after Nov 15th, 2016

The config.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id = "pt.com.extensionWorker" versionCode="28"  version   = "3.0.5">
        <name>nameHere</name>
        <description>DescriptionHere</description>
    <author href="authorHere" email="semailHere">authorTextHere </author>
    <gap:platform name="android" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.dialogs"  />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" source="npm" version="0.7.10" />
    <preference name="orienation" value="landscape" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="5000"/>
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/android/hdpiSplash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/android/mdpiSplash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/android/hdpiSplash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/android/xhdpiSplash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
    </feature>
    <allow-navigation href="http://domain1/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://domain2/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://domain2/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://domain3/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://domain3/*" />
</widget>
```

What is the right config to now include the camera plugin?

Comment: Please check the solution in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995204/phonegap-build-error-plugin-unsupported#tab-top